# Modify or Disable HTML for "Sales Order - Send by Email" template

Tags: odoo, html-email, odoo-10

How to change Sales Order - Send by Email template, not the text but style of the sent mail.

For example, change header/footer color or if possible completely disable HTML and send all e-mail messages as plain text.

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution Carlo. Would love to see where that wrapper template is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is pulling from the Sale Order Notification Email. I went into Settings > Technical > Email > Templates, searched for that Notification Email template and replaced the Content with the following:

`${object.body | safe}`

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in the paynow and other Views that apply to the mail model.

Look in table mail.message and see which layout it's using.

Comment: Please add more details and clarity to your answer.